# Two x axes and two y axes

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, xetex

I need a pgfplot with 2 x-axis at the bottom und 2 y-axis on the left side. In my example, both x and y axes are on top of each other. How do I move these axes apart?

```
[![\begin{figure}\[h\]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{set layers},
\begin{axis}\[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
%xlabel={Watt \[\unit{\watt}\]},
%ylabel={Dezibel \[\unit{dB\m}\]},
axis y line*=left,
xmode=log,
xmin=1, xmax=10000,
ymin=0, ymax=40,
domain=1:10000,
xticklabels={\qty{1}{\mW}, \qty{10}{\mW}, \qty{100}{\mW}, \qty{1}{\watt}, \qty{10}{\watt}}, 
log ticks with fixed point, x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
grid=both
\]
\addplot \[very thick\] {10*log10(x)};
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}\[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
xlabel={Watt \[\unit{\watt}\]},
ylabel={Dezibel \[\unit{dB\m}\]},
axis y line*=left,
axis x line*=none,
xmode=log,
xmin=1, xmax=10000,
ymin=-40, ymax=0,
xticklabels={\qty{100}{\nano\watt}, \qty{1}{\micro\watt}, \qty{10}{\micro\watt}, \qty{100}{\micro\watt}, \qty{1}{\mW}}, 
log ticks with fixed point, x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
grid=both
\]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Leistung in Dezibelmeter \[dBm\]}
\label{fig:leistung-in-dezibelmeter}
\end{figure}][1]][1]
```

[image: Example]

Comment: Does adding `axis line shift=10mm` to the second axis result in the output you expect?

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure whether this is what you're after, but you can use the option `axis line shift` to shift the axis lines away from the plot

```
\documentclass[border=10mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
%xlabel={Watt \[\unit{\watt}\]},
%ylabel={Dezibel \[\unit{dB\m}\]},
axis y line*=left,
xmode=log,
xmin=1, xmax=10000,
ymin=0, ymax=40,
domain=1:10000,
xticklabels={\qty{1}{\mW}, \qty{10}{\mW}, \qty{100}{\mW}, \qty{1}{\watt}, \qty{10}{\watt}}, 
log ticks with fixed point, x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
grid=both
]
\addplot [very thick] {10*log10(x)};
\end{axis}

\begin{axis}[
width=0.8\textwidth,
scale only axis,
xlabel={Watt [\unit{\watt}]},
ylabel={Dezibel [\unit{dB\m}]},
axis y line*=left,
axis x line*=none,
xmode=log,
xmin=1, xmax=10000,
ymin=-40, ymax=0,
xticklabels={\qty{100}{\nano\watt}, \qty{1}{\micro\watt}, \qty{10}{\micro\watt}, \qty{100}{\micro\watt}, \qty{1}{\mW}}, 
log ticks with fixed point, x tick label style={/pgf/number format/1000 sep=\,},
grid=both,
axis line shift=10mm,
]
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help.